# App causing Force Close in Application Manager

Tags: android, google-play

When my app is installed from Google Play, it causes a the Application Manager on Android 2.1-update1 to force close (Android settings, Applications, Manage applications). When installed through Eclipse/ADB, however, the problem doesn't occur.

Here the exception:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.android.settings.ManageApplications$AppInfoAdapter.bulkUpdateLabels(ManageApplications.java:1197)
    at com.android.settings.ManageApplications$1.handleMessage(ManageApplications.java:404)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It appears to go paired with many warnings from the ResourceType and PackageManager:

```
W/ResourceType(  696): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
W/PackageManager(  696): Failure retrieving text 0x0 in package com.android.providers.drm
W/PackageManager(  696): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
W/PackageManager(  696):        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:200)
W/PackageManager(  696):        at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationContext.java:2306)
W/PackageManager(  696):        at com.android.settings.ManageApplications$ResourceLoaderThread.run(ManageApplications.java:771)
```

Comment: and here I go with my the crystal ball: its a runtime exception... fix it! --- ironie off: What is the error in your logcat?

Comment: Added the Log above, maybe there is a missing parameter in manifest? The Error is shown, when I try to start the Application Manger

Comment: There is no array used by `bulkUpdateLabels()` in the current code. My guess is that there is something unusual with your activity or application label.

Comment: @CommonsWare: my Application Label i set with android:label="@string/app_name" - When I install it by Eclipse, everything works fine... but not from Market

Comment: @Christoph I ran into the same problem, and have edited your question to improve its description. I'm encountering this on an HTC Hero running Android 2.1-update1.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've been experiencing this on precisely *one* device. It seems to me to be a HTC Hero-specific bug. Unfortunately, I don't have any other 2.1-update1 devices to test on.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma I've tested it with a HTC Desire

Comment: @Christoph Seems indeed HTC-specific. Which version of Android is it running?

Comment: Unfortunately Android 2.2.2